# Guardar y mostrar arreglo con valores generados

Tags: java, array

Necesito crear un arreglo de fichas de dos valores cada una (v1,v2) simulando fichas de domino.

El problema es que cuando guardo las fichas en el arreglo solo me guarda el ultimo valor. Mostrando el arreglo entero como que todas la fichas son (*seis-seis*), esperando que me muestre las 28 fichas tal que así: (*zero-zero, zero-uno, zero-dos* ... *seis-cinco, seis-seis*).

El `System.out.println(f)` me muestra cada ficha correctamente tal como quiero que este en el arreglo.

El código:

```
public void mostrarArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayFitxes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ArrayFitxes[i].toString());
        }
    }

    public void generarArray() {

        int posicio = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= 6; j++) {
                f.v1 = i;
                f.v2 = j;
            System.out.println(f);//muestra correctamente la ficha
                ArrayFitxes[posicio] = f;
                posicio++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás modificando siempre el mismo objeto, en lugar de crear un nuevo objeto. Entonces el arreglo solamente contiene 36 referencias al mismo objeto `Ficha`.

Para solucionarlo, dentro del `loop` interno, a la variable `f` le tenés que asignar una nueva referencia.

```
public void generarArray() {

    int posicio = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 6; j++) {

            f = new Ficha()//Acá se crea un nuevo objeto de tipo Ficha
            f.v1 = i;
            f.v2 = j;
        System.out.println(f);//muestra correctamente la ficha
            ArrayFitxes[posicio] = f;//Se asigna el nuevo objeto y no el mismo de siempre
            posicio++;
        }
    }
}
```

Inicialmente tenías a `f` apuntando siempre a la misma posición de memoria. Con la modificación, cada vez que se crea el objeto, `f` referencia a una nueva posición de memoria sin perder los datos de la anterior. De esta manera, a cada posición del arreglo se le asigna un objeto distinto, es decir, referencian a una posición de memoria distinta.